# Is it possible to detect an active spinning beach ball programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cpu-usage

I've written an Mac OS application which is taking lot's of resources. 
(video processing)

Now I've discovered that on old machines with low RAM or if the user is doing some multitasking it may happen that apples spinning beachball is appearing often.

I would like to make my application more user friendly and throttle down the processing a little bit to make the computer more responsive. To establish that I would like to detect if the beachball is active to reduce threads.

Is there any function or method in xcode / Foundation / Cocoa / ObjC / Swift which can tell my application whether the beach ball is active?

Thanks in advance,

Jack

Comment: Is it possible that you're doing work on the GUI thread which is causing the "beach ball" to appear whilst this work is finished?

Comment: No, just sometimes updating UI elements. My question is not about my application is causing the beach ball. I just want to be nice, if the beach ball appears. I discovered that since Apple introduced Yosemite 4GB RAM is not enough and causing a lot of application be stuck with the beach ball. I just want my application to be nice to the system if thrashing begins.